# How to left align footer element in GridView

Tags: gridview, footer

I am getting problem in alignment of element that is in FooterTemplate of GridView.
Anyone suggest me how to do it.The Code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvComment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
OnRowDataBound="gvComment_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="gvComment_RowCreated" Width="100%" ShowHeader="false" BorderWidth="0px" ShowFooter="true">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:10%"><img id="imgUser" src="" alt="" title="" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                        comment comment
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNameComments" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:7px;"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;background-image:url(../Images/dotted_line.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:center;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:7px;"></td></tr>
            </table>            
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <FooterTemplate >
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    Footer Text
                   Footer Text
                   Footer Text         
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have set align property of td left but it doesn't work.Page output shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add `align="left"` on the table from  `<FooterTemplate >` ?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="left">
<tr>
    <td align="left">
       Footer Text
       Footer Text
       Footer Text         
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually there was some alignment issues.Now i have done it.Thanks Adrian.