# How to adjust footer template horizontal align?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I would like to adjust footer template horizontal align as left in grid but, it's not working any one can explain please. this is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grd_View" ShowFooter="True" runat="server" OnRowEditing="Grd_View_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="CustomerCode" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="Grd_View_RowCommand" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="True" 
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="style2"  ForeColor="#333333" OnRowDataBound="Grd_View_RowDataBound" 
            OnRowDeleting="Grd_View_RowDeleting" >
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#555555" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCode" HeaderText="Customer Code" InsertVisible="False"
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="CustomerName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TellNo" HeaderText="Tell No" SortExpression="TellNo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FaxNo" HeaderText="Fax No" SortExpression="FaxNo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PIC"   HeaderText="Person in Contact" SortExpression="PIC" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate> <asp:LinkButton ForeColor="white" ID="btnNew" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="New" Text="New">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
               </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

             <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#777777" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#555555" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />


        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: have you tried FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"?

Comment: its not working that option is not there in Footer template and i have tried in template field also its not working...

Comment: there are another two things you can try, you can try setting style="text-align:left;" in your linkButton of the footer. Or you can put a table element inside the footerTemplate and set align=left like in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439211/how-to-left-align-footer-element-in-gridview. if you can post an image of what you want to achieve that would be more helpful.

Comment: @Black Baron - i inserted full code in my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason your footer template will always be in right is because you are creating it as the last column in the GridView along with the Delete column.

To solve this you need to create the footer template **in the first column** or I'll recommend just putting the footer template inside with edit template field in the first column and the delete template field in the second column.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the below:

```
<FooterTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton ForeColor="white" ID="btnNew" runat="server" CommandName="New" Text="New">
    </asp:LinkButton>
</FooterTemplate>
<FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```